# Webpack/Angular - Materialize not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, webpack, materialize

I downloaded a starter Asp.net & Angular2 project [here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/). I'm trying to add materialize to my project, but it doesn’t seem to be loading when I run the project. How do i configure materialize properly with webpack and/or Angular, does it require a special loader? Thanks guys, im new to webpack.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "First",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extendify": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "typescript": "^1.8.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "angular2-universal": "^0.104.5",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^1.0.2",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.7",
    "preboot": "^2.0.10",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
}
```

wepback.config.vendor

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
var isDevelopment = process.env.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT === 'Development';

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '', '.js' ]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            { test: /\.css/, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css']) }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            'bootstrap',
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'materialize-css',
            'es6-shim',
            'style-loader',
            'jquery',
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router',
            '@angular/platform-server',
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]_[hash]',
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
    ].concat(isDevelopment ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warnings: false },
            minimize: true,
            mangle: false // Due to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6678
        })
    ])
};
```

home.hmlt

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m6">
            <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                <div class="card-content white-text">
                    <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                    <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
                    I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                    <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                    <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to user the materilize-css Webpack loader:
https://github.com/Zevran/materialize-loader
Snippets from their site (after you npm i -D materialize-loader url-loader file-loader):

1. Load font config: 
   `loaders: [
     { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader:"url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
     { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file" }
   ]`
2. require materialize: `require("materialize-loader");`

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but did this work?  I cant get this to work, I have been trying to get this to work in my react app.  I can use a materialize-css className, but no variables in scss.